# Entity Framework and "ViewModel"

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, layers

Earlier I asked a question about "Entity Framework and layer seperation" and found out that some people use a ViewModel to show their data in the UI.

For example if we got a "Person" table and an "Address" table and I want to show a combination of the two tables. I would then create a ViewModel, lets call it PersonAddress, and show it on the UI.

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. How do you save the "PersonAddress" object to the database since it does not exist in my EF context?
2. If I only wanted to show the "Person" object, would I still create an identical "ViewModel" object to the one EF creates for me (without the EF specific properties ofcourse)
3. Do people use the "EntityState" property and dosent it become useless if you only interact with the "ViewModel"?

Answer (score 6):

> How do you best save the "PersonAddress" object to the database since it does not exist in my EF context?

You don't. You save a `Person` and the attached `Address` separately (in a transaction, if needed). Loading data and saving data can also be thought as different concerns (see [CQRS](http://www.cqrsinfo.com/)).

> If I only wanted to show the "Person" object, would I still create an identical "ViewModel" object to the one EF creates for me (without the EF specific properties of course)

Yes. Again, this is about separation of concerns.

> Do people use the "EntityState" property and dosent it become useless if you only interact with the "ViewModel"?

Depends on what you are doing. A `ViewModel` models the UI, not your data.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers.
About the 3rd one. What would my "PersonAddress" object look like? Im asking because i havent created one yet. I assume it would contain the properties I want to show along with the PersonId and AddressId for select/update/delete things.
Then after ive selected and updated Person and Address with the new information, I can use the "EntityState" for whatever I like. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: It pretty much would mirror the UI. It wouldn't have the Id fields if they are not displayed. I'd expect an `Add/Update Person` and `Add/Update Address for person` views to also exist and handle those specific actions.

Comment: Hm, im not sure I understand. Lets say you show a list of "PersonAddress" and you want to update row no. 2. How do you know which Person to update in the db if you only have information like name and age in the ViewModel? I might need an example of some sort hehe

Comment: @Thomas - If the view requires the Id's, then they should be part of the `ViewModel`.

Comment: +1 for `A ViewModel models the UI, not your data`